# How would I achieve a horizontal and vertical hover effect up to a hovered element in a table: How do I create an intersecting hover?

Tags: html, jquery, css, html-table

[image: Effect I'm looking to achieve]

I have a table which has a vertical and horizontal title ("Initial Gravity" and "Final Gravity" respectively), I have a hover effect on my  elements, but what I would really like is for my hover to intersect in a manner similar to that shown in the image.

I've used red rectangles in the image purely for representation purposes, I'm hoping to use the same hover as is seen on the hovered element, so the result I'm looking to achieve is a purple bar across the row and a purple bar down the column intersecting on the element the user is hovering over.

If code is needed to help get help, please let me know what code you need to see. The table is a monster at 56 rows and 28 cols so not sure if I should add the entire code or just a snippet.

```css
.card-body table{
      width:100%;
    }
    .blank-cell, th{
      background: #000;
      color: #fff;
    }
    td {
        text-align: center;
    }

    th{
      background: #000;
      color: #fff;
    }

    td:hover {
        background: #530288;
        color:white;
    }
```

```html
<table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th>
            <div><strong>Final Gravity</strong></div>
          </th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      
      <tbody>
        <tr class="row-2">
          <td class="blank-cell"></td>
          <td class="tooltip"></td>
          <td class="tooltip">0.990</td>
          <td class="tooltip">0.992</td>
          <td class="tooltip">0.994</td>          
        </tr>      
        <tr class="row-3">
          <td class="blank-cell"><strong>Initial Gravity</strong></td>
          <td class="tooltip">1.020</td>
          <td class="tooltip">3.9</td>
          <td class="tooltip">3.7</td>
          <td class="tooltip">3.4</td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="row-4">
          <td class="blank-cell"></td>
          <td class="tooltip">1.022</td>
          <td class="tooltip">4.2</td>
          <td class="tooltip">3.9</td>
          <td class="tooltip">3.7</td>      
       </tr>
       <tr class="row-5">
          <td class="blank-cell"></td>
          <td class="tooltip">1.024</td>
          <td class="tooltip">4.5</td>
          <td class="tooltip">4.2</td>
          <td class="tooltip">3.9</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: One could argue that it's daft to post a question about code and not show any. We get tired of having our time wasted when we're trying to help. Now you know. :)

Comment: @isherwood Equally sound logic I suppose. Just wasn't sure what would be helpful so thought I'd ask first :)

Comment: Good question, if none or you don't figure it out by tomorrow, I can give it a shot. Would be a handy script. In mean time perhaps this can suffice [https://css-tricks.com/simple-css-row-column-highlighting/](https://css-tricks.com/simple-css-row-column-highlighting/)

Comment: @GhostPengy That's a great jumping off point for what I'm looking for. Feel free to fire up an answer including that url or to create a wee snippet of your own whenever you get the chance.  :)

Comment: Why did this get closed? The reason I'm given is "This question needs debugging details. It is not currently accepting answers.
Edit the question to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. This will help others answer the question." It describes the desired behaviour, specific problem and provides code. I'm confused.

Comment: @Twisted it is not clear from the question what you want to achieve , as you said intersection of hover (what you mean by that) , as of now your code is working fine giving purple background to hovered element which is the intersection of row and column . Be more clear and specific , so community can have direct approach and help you . If it is not clear some members close the question for clarity and debugging . You can reopen the question with modification (more clarity) . The option is present just above the **Post Question** btn

Comment: @Rana It is very clear what I am looking to achieve, GhostPengy has offered a link which shows they understood perfectly what it is I'm looking for and as far as I know the other users understood too. Please reopen this question, you not understanding does not mean everyone doesn't understand. It is obvious what is meant by intersect and there is also an image provided showing the effect I'm looking to achieve.

Comment: @Twisted I haven't closed the question and not have the power to **open/close** questions , I just replied for your query about closing of question as many of my question has been closed .Then why you have written - **I've used red rectangles in the image purely for representation purposes**

Comment: @Rana reading further in to that sentence you will see that I mention the effect I'm looking to achieve, the red rectangles are representational of where the hover effect should cover. I appreciate your input but I don't believe users misunderstanding the question is the reason for the questions closure.

Comment: @Twisted Sorry for the delay, but here it is, I left CSS and formating up to you, just have the basic mechanics working: (https://jsfiddle.net/dLj7r482)[https://jsfiddle.net/dLj7r482]. On the side, even tho your question is ok by my standards, it might not be by others. And it seems you got quite a few downvotes for your initial question, in the future try to put all the information beforehand. I will leave this as it is atm, no point opening the pandora box.

Comment: @GhostPengy Thanks for getting back to me but unfortunately the link you just posted 404s me :(... Correction I made it work by trimming bits off the url  https://jsfiddle.net/dLj7r482 for anyone else that may find this useful :)